# Distribution of a sum of large number of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, uniform-convergence

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with $E[X_{i}]=\mu$ and $D^{2}[X_{i}]=\sigma^2$. Furthermore, let $F_{X}$ denote a cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$ and $\Phi$ – the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal random variable. Finally, let $S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ and $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ – normal random variable with parameters $\mu$, $\sigma^2.$

I want to prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for every $n>N$ and every $x$
$$\mid F_{S_{n}}(x)-F_{\mathcal{N}(n\mu,n\sigma^2)}(x)\mid <\epsilon.$$

My proof:

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

By the central limit theorem there exists $N$ such that for every $n>N$ and every $x$
$$\mid F_{\frac{S_{n}-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}}(x)-\Phi(x)\mid <\epsilon.$$
So $$ \mid F_{S_{n}}(\sigma\sqrt{n}x+n\mu)-\Phi(x)\mid <\epsilon.$$
Now if we let $x'=\sigma\sqrt{n}x+n\mu$
$$ \mid F_{S_{n}}(x')-\Phi(\frac{x'-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}})\mid <\epsilon.$$
But $\Phi(\frac{x-n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}})=F_{\mathcal{N}(n\mu,n\sigma^2)}(x)$, which concludes the proof.

Is this correct?

Comment: For convergence in distribution (and the weak central limit theorem) $N$ depends on $x$.

Comment: @LinAlg
Could you provide some counterexample? This part of my proof was basen on the book A First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross. He noted at the end of the proof of this theorem that the convergence may be shown uniform. Thanks.